# extjs treepanel expand collapse event

Tags: extjs, treepanel

I have a treepanel with nodes inside the treepanel. To identify whether the treepanel and not the nodes that are expanded or collapsed I use the following code:

Ext.getCmp('general').collapsed

The return value is either true or false. Is there an event in treepanel that I can capture when the treepanel is expanded or collapsed? I mean the treepanel and not the nodes in the panel.

Your help is kindly appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must do something wrong here, the following code works, see this **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/33rX6/)**

```
Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', {
    collapsible: true,
    title: 'Simple Tree',
    width: 200,
    height: 150,
    store: store,
    rootVisible: false,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    listeners: {
        collapse: function() {
            alert('collapsed');
        },
        expand: function() {
            alert('expand')
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried adding the collapse and expand event in my listener and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Then you'll need to share some more code, because this works for me and should work for you. Where and how do you declare the listeners?

Comment: id: 'accountTreePnl',
    name: 'accountTreePnl',
    height: 250,
    xtype : "treepanel",
    rootVisible: false,
    border: false,
    animate : false,
    autoScroll : true,
    containerScroll : true,
    root: new Ext.tree.AsyncTreeNode({
    text: 'Account(s)'
    }),
    loader: new Ext.tree.TreeLoader({
    dataUrl: ''
    }),
    dropConfig : {
    appendOnly : true
    },
    listeners: {
    collapse: function() {
    },
    expand: function() {
    }
    }

Comment: @EugeneAnthony based on that example your tree isn't collapsible at all. So I guess you are collapsing a container into which you have nested the tree?

Comment: The tree panel is inside a panel that uses the fit layout.

Comment: @EugeneAnthony Again; **based on that example your tree isn't collapsible at all!** It seems that you are collapsing the panel with the fit layout. In that case now event on treepanel get fired

Comment: Done. Perhaps this question might interest you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14993104/extjs-combo-box-disabled-properties-not-functioning

Answer (score 1):

'expand' and 'collapse' don't work for me neither. Instead, 'itemcollapse', 'itemexpand', 'itemmove' and their peers do work for me. I'm with Ext-JS 4.2.1.

Comment: You used the wrong event. You need to use afteritemexpand event.

afteritemexpand: function ( node, index, item, eOpts ){
    alert('Dharmesh');
}
Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/johanhaest/RDC9W/1/

Answer (score 0):

You used the wrong event. You need to use afteritemexpand event.

```
afteritemexpand: function ( node, index, item, eOpts ){
    alert('HAHA');
}
```

Here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/johanhaest/RDC9W/1/