# ExtJS combo box disabled properties not functioning

Tags: extjs, combobox

I attempted to disable the combo box component with the disabled attribute however it's not working. The code is below:

```
xtype: 'bkl.exchange.ExchangeRFCombo',
disabled: true,
fieldLabel: 'Exchange',
id: 'exchMapee',
valueField: 'omsMappingCode',
editable: false
```

The mode is remote and not local. So the values displayed by the combo box is from the database. Is there a solution to this problem?

Your help is kindly appreciated.

Thank You.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"? Post more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this to the combo box:

```
listeners: {
             'afterRender': function () {
                 this.disable();
             }
         }
```

That will disable the box after being rendered.

Comment: it makes no sense using the `afterrender` (events are lowercase) event here. Setting the property before rendering will render is disabled